# Returning Mysqli in JSON Dict

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am retrieving data from a mysql database and would like to return it as a JSON dict.

```
<?php
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
   die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT tbldomainpricing.extension, tblpricing.msetupfee
FROM `tblpricing`
INNER JOIN tbldomainpricing ON tbldomainpricing.id = tblpricing.relid 
WHERE tblpricing.type = 'domainregister'
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$all_rows = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $all_rows []= $row['extension'] . ":" . $row['msetupfee'];
}
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($all_rows);
?>
```

The return :

{"extension":".com","msetupfee":"6.99"},{"extension":".net","msetupfee":"6.99"},

How do I get the return to be

{"com":"6.99"},{"net":"6.99"}

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $all_rows[$row['extension']] = $row['msetupfee'];
}
```

Ref u_mulder's comment, you might also want this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $all_rows[][$row['extension']] = $row['msetupfee'];
}
```

Comment: This will be `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]` But maybe OP wants this exactly.

Comment: I have added an alternative for the exact output, though this may not be the most efficient format

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but probably you need something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $all_rows[] = array($row['extension'], $row['msetupfee']);
}
```